# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, syntax, nopcommerce

In **nopcommerce 4.3**, when I am calling the **javascript** at page load time in **view** page(themes\views\abc.cshtml) at that time it showing error in console application. i.e. **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**.

Here is my code,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
    });
</script>
```

Totally Surprised...!!! Why this error showing. Because I don't think so that is any mistakes in **syntax**. And this type of error throw when there is **mismatch** of **javascript** / **jquery** related **file** path. But in nopcommerce all file is available.

Comment: Make sure libraries are imported before your script

Comment: Also make sure you don't have `$.noConflict()` before your code and there are no other errors in the console/network tab (eg 404 or http when it should be https)

Comment: Post the generated HTML and look for jQuery3.5.1.min

Answer (score 1):

In nopCommerce 4.2, I got the error `$(...).fineUploader is not a function`

The solution is to put the scripts at the footer, like in the examples below.

Note the use of `ResourceLocation.Footer` and `asp-location="Footer"`

```
Html.AddCssFileParts(ResourceLocation.Footer, "~/lib/fineuploader/fine-uploader.min.css");
Html.AddScriptParts(ResourceLocation.Footer, "~/lib/fineuploader/jquery.fine-uploader.min.js");
```

```
<script asp-location="Footer">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#@clientId").fineUploader({...});
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not imported before your Script.

View source of the generated HTML page and see if your script is placed after jQuery import, if not place your script at proper section.

You can add a custom section like below

```
@section Scripts{

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
    });
</script>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is not imported. You can Import Jquery in your view page using @Html.AddScriptParts().